# MS Edge fails to render nested flex layout properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

Here is the layout that shows the problem that I have faced, also can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/51z7vt23/

```css
.box {
     width: auto;
     height: 40px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     flex: 0 0 auto;
     position: relative;
}
.txt {
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
     font-size: 18px;
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     width: 0px;
     position: relative;
}
.container {
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 3rem;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     max-width: 100%;
     text-align: start;
     flex: 0 0 auto;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
}
.container2 {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 3rem;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex: 1 0 auto;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      max-width: 100%;
      text-align: start;
      align-items: center;
      height: auto;           
}
.parent {
       width: 400px;
       border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="container2">
               <div class="box">YES</div>
                <div class="txt">REALLY REALLLY REAAAAALLLY REAAAAALLLY REAAAAALLLY BEAUTIFULL TEXT, PERHAPS THE MOST BEAUTIFULL TEXT IN THE WORLD</div>
           </div>
           <div class="box">NO</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This code runs fine with Chrome and provides the expected result:
[image]
 but with MS Edge I can see that the "NO" box is pushed out of container boundaries:
[image]

Version of MS Edge that I am using is 44.17763.771.0

Does anyone know how to make it worked as desired with MS EDGE?

Comment: `max-width: 100%;` on `cotainer2` is too much if it has to share the parent with `box` (NO). Does https://jsfiddle.net/8f9suq7k/ works better ?

Comment: @G-Cyr you could post your code as an answer. I've tested it in Edge and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You may remove `max-width:100%;` on `.container2` , which is too much since the width is to be shared with another element. You can turn it into `min-width:100%;`+/or `overflow:hidden;` as sort of a reflow/recalculation of its size.

demo below

```css
.box {
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.txt {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 18px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.container2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 3rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: start;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="box">YES</div>
      <div class="txt">REALLY REALLLY REAAAAALLLY REAAAAALLLY REAAAAALLLY BEAUTIFULL TEXT, PERHAPS THE MOST BEAUTIFULL TEXT IN THE WORLD</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">NO</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

forked https://jsfiddle.net/8f9suq7k/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you notice, but your `<div class="box">NO</div>` is outside the `container2`

https://jsfiddle.net/xu1sagy2/

```css
 .box {
     width: auto;
     height: 40px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     flex: 0 0 auto;
     position: relative;
}
 .txt {
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
     font-size: 18px;
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     width: 0px;
     position: relative;
}
 .container {
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 3rem;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     max-width: 100%;
     text-align: start;
     flex: 0 0 auto;
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
}
 .container2{
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 3rem;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     max-width: 100%;
     text-align: start;
     align-items: center;
     height: auto;
}
 .parent {
     width: 400px;
     border: 1px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="container2">

            <div class="box">YES</div>

            <div class="txt">REALLY REALLLY REAAAAALLLY REAAAAALLLY REAAAAALLLY BEAUTIFULL TEXT, PERHAPS THE MOST BEAUTIFULL TEXT IN THE WORLD</div>

            <div class="box">NO</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's how the original code has been built, I just reduced it to the minimal reproducible sample

Answer (score 0):

try

```
> .box { flex: 0 0 auto;
> -ms- flex: 0 0 auto; }
> 
> .txt { flex: 1 0 auto;
> -ms- flex: 1 0 auto; }
> 
> .container { flex: 0 0 auto;
> -ms- flex: 0 0 auto; }
> 
> .container2 { flex: 1 0 auto;
> -ms- flex: 1 0 auto; }
```

Note that I did not type all your css code, just focused on the "flex" sections.
The "-ms-" part has worked for me in IE, please try it for Edge.

Comment: Not tested in edge but in ie11 and it works without prefix.